# MS Visual Studio Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debug

Previously, when my program crashed during debugging VS would bring me to a line of code where crash happened. Now... its always looks like this:

[image]

And i have no clue where and why it crashed :(

I realise that i incidentally changed VS configurations, but i dont know how to get it back.
Pls, give me an advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Debug -> Exceptions... you can add the ability to break on the *Command Language Runtime Exceptions* when the exception is *Thrown*.

That should then place you right at the point the exception begins to surface within your code.

Comment: yes, thats what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can click on View Detail to drill into the real exception. Depending on where the exception occurs it may be wrapped by another exception like the one you are seeing.